# sqlite query problem - possible two solutions?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am a student of a web application development module.
We have had a database examination, and I have a small question that you may be able to clarify for me.

It is an exercise that I think could be done in two ways, but according to my teacher only one option is correct.

I have looked and believe in this case two queries could apply. If you could clarify my confusion a bit, I thank you =)

I leave the question of the statement, the tables and two solutions. Would both be okay?

Exercise: It returns a list with the identifiers of the clients that have requested a command. Note that it should not display identifiers that are repeating. They must be ordered.

[image]

If there are foreigns keys. I add the keys to the tables. Thank you very much, it has been very useful.
Table comanda:
[Table comanda](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAJcq.jpg)

Table cliente:
[Table cliente](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZtGJ.jpg)

Queries:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id_cliente as 'Identificador cliente'
FROM comanda
ORDER BY id_cliente ASC;
```

```
SELECT DISTINCT cliente.id
FROM cliente INNER JOIN comanda
ON cliente.id = comanda.id_cliente
ORDER BY cliente.id;
```

Many thanks =)

Comment: If the task was formulated exactly as presented then your teacher is wrong. If any other fields from `cliente` (like name) should be in the output then you need `JOIN`.

Comment: @PM77-1: I think you're missing the case when (no proper constraints are in place and) there are values in `comanda.id_cliente` that do not exist in `cliente.id`. Then the queries are at least not equivalent. Which one is correct leaves room for interpretation of the text of the task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's one subtle difference: If there are values in `comanda.id_cliente` that do not exist in `cliente.id`, the first query will output them, the second doesn't because they'll find no match for the join.

It is not unreasonable to *assume* that `(comanda.id_cliente)` is constrained to be a foreign key referencing `(cliente.id)` though. Such a declaration would make such orphaned values in `comanda.id_cliente` impossible. And such a constraint should normally in place, if the database is well designed. But the picture doesn't seem to indicate such a constraint (unless I'm missing something). So unless there's further information indeed showing that such a constraint exists, the assumption might be proven wrong.

So *generally* spoken, the queries are not equivalent, I'm afraid. Which one is *correct* in terms of the task leaves room for interpretation of the text of the task though.

Comment: Yes. there are foreigns keys. I add the keys to the tables. Thank you very much, it has been very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Both queries work and would generate the result that is expected.

The first query is more efficient than the second one: there is no need to bring the client table to generate the result you want.

It should also be noted that using single quotes for identifiers (here, column alias `Identificador cliente`) should generally be avoided. In standard SQL, single quotes stand for literal strings. The standard quoting character for identifiers is double quotes.

Comment: I think you're missing the case when (no proper constraints are in place and) there are values in `comanda.id_cliente` that do not exist in `cliente.id`. Then the queries are at least not equivalent. Which one is correct leaves room for interpretation of the text of the task.

Comment: Great. thank you. Note the double and single quotes too =)

Answer (score 0):

Both answers could be accepted. But it depends a lot on the teacher and how much are the exercises clarified.

1. Query

   - Pro:  Efficient and simple
   - Cons: There could be records with non-existing client id. In this case, the exercise should mention this.
2. Query

   - Pro:  More precise
   - Cons: That join could be unnecessary

It would interesting to ask the teacher about the reason. A teacher could expect any of the answers.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I have class with that teacher tomorrow so I will ask her again in more detail =)